# Derivation of holdness of positivity of $~\left(x-a\right)+\sqrt{b^2+\left(x-a\right)^2}~$with$~a,b\in\mathbb R_{> 0}~~,~~ 0 \leq x \leq a $

Tags: systems-of-equations, real-numbers

$$0\leq x\leq a\in\mathbb R_{>0}$$

$$b\in\mathbb R_{>0}$$

$$f\left(x\right):=\left(x-a\right)+\sqrt{b^2+\left(x-a\right)^2}\tag{1}$$

I want to prove that the function$~f\left(x\right)~$always take a positive value.

$$f\left(x\right)|_{x=a}=\left(a-a\right)+\sqrt{b^2+\left(a-a\right)^2}=\sqrt{b^2}=|b|=b>0~~\leftarrow~~~~\text{Obviously positive}$$

$$f\left(x\right)|_{x=0}=\left(0-a\right)+\sqrt{b^2+\left(0-a\right)^2}=-a+\sqrt{b^2+a^2}~~\leftarrow~~~~\text{Seemingly unclear of positive}\tag{2}$$

Any good way to prove the non-negativity?

About eqn2,

$$f\left(x\right)|_{x=0}=\underbrace{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}_{~~\text{this value}~>~a}-a>0$$

Seemingly as$~a>1~$is held, then my above claim is definitely correct but as$~a<1~$is held, I can't have a confidence of that claim($~~~\text{this value}~>~a~$).

Comment: One possible approach is to prove that the part with the square root is always larger than $|x-a|$ so $f(x) = (x-a) + |x-a| + C$ where $C > 0$. Then after adding everything you're left with a positive number i.e., if $x-a$ is negative, you're left with $C$ otherwise you're left with $2|x-a| + C$ which is positive.

Comment: I think I got what you meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$  \left(x-a\right)+\sqrt{b^2+\left(x-a\right)^2}  \tag{1}  $$

$$ \sqrt{b^2+\left(x-a\right)^2} = \left| x-a \right|  + C \tag{2}  $$

$$  C > 0  \tag{3}  $$

Now eqn1 can be rewritten as below.

$$   \left(x-a\right)  +\left| x-a \right| + C  \tag{3}  $$

$$   0 \leq x \leq a   \tag{4}  $$

Since tag4 is held , basically the leftmost term of eqn3 takes a negative value.

$$  \therefore ~~ \underbrace{- \left| x-a \right|}_{\text{previous leftmost term} }  + \left| x-a \right| + C = C > 0 ~\rightarrow~\text{QED}   $$